# Chromecast not able to play all videos

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm making an application for chrome cast i was able to play  http://iptvcanales.com/xw/peliculas.php?movie=006 
 with chromecast  application but not able to play 
http://200.76.77.237/LIVE/H01/CANAL495/PROFILE03.m3u8?-1332%2F1499-20150816T153535.ts=-1 
is there any specific reason for this ?if anybody know solution please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this working demo from this link - https://github.com/PaulTR/AndroidDemoProjects/tree/master/Chromecast

Go to string.xml and change the video_url which you want to play and run application it will play your video on TV.

For your reference have a look : https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-an-android-google-cast-sender-app/161

Hope you will get some help from here.

Comment: yes i m running url on the demo right now but it cast first one but not the scond.

Comment: @Raj then you should check your URL with multiple browser there might be some problem with it.

Comment: ok actually video plays on application but not on chrome cast might be the url issue.

Comment: @Raj yea one video_url is working and second one is not so its look like url issue only.